# D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan by itself every few seconds

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-galaxy

I'm developing an app that needs to function on new and older devices. This app needs to continuously scan for BLE advertisements. It is crucial that no advertisement is lost and crucial but less so, that the advertisement is received by the app the moment it is sent.

On newer phones like my S10+, I don't see any issue. When disabling power optimizations, installing a ScanFilter and running a foreground service, the app has no problem continuously scanning in the background. However, when I test on phones like an S6 or S7, with the exact same app, with power optimizations disabled, with a ScanFilter, foreground service, etc, I seem to scan continuously for around 10 seconds and I get a "D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan" in the ADB console. I am not calling stop scan and I am sure of it. The even stranger thing is the scan doesn't really stop completely, it seems I am able to receive new advertisements every five seconds for a short amount of time, lets say 500ms. This is not good enough for me, however, as I need to ensure I get every single advertisement.

I've also seen the issue is exasperated when the phone sleeps/screen turns off. A foreground service should prevent this I would think?

I don't currently use a wakelock, but is it possibly necessary on older devices?

The S6 and S7 are running Android 6 and 7.

Also, to clarify, I cannot change how the device I'm interfacing with works. I'm also aware this is a strange use case.

This is how I start my scan. This code is ran by the onCreate of a foreground service that is started on Boot by a startService call pre Oreo and a startForegroundService post Oreo.

```
val filter = ScanFilter.Builder()
filter.setManufacturerData(1361, byteArrayOf())

var settings = ScanSettings.Builder()
settings.setScanMode(SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)

        bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner?.startScan(mutableListOf(filter.build()), settings.build(), scanCallback)
```

Comment: why not use altbeacon library for that

Comment: @abdul I haven't tested altbeacon but I guess it possibly can work if I make a new beaconparser. I'm just not sure it will do anything. And... I currently have around 20 lines of code max for BLE code so its super simple and I would like to fix the error.